# Converting PHP CURL query to C#'s HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, php, curl, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest in C# to do a POST to a particular API. The problem is that the system on the other end does not receive the body of the request. More so, when trying to send the request via tools like Postman, I have the same issue. The only thing that seems to work is a PHP implementation, detailed below.
My best guess is that I'm missing some header or another that the PHP sets automatically.
Has anybody encountered a similar problem/does anyone have a clue what I'm missing?

Both implementations below.

```php
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $url = <<the APIs url>>
        $hash = base64_encode('<<username>>:<password>>');
        $data = [];
  $username  = <<username>>
  $password =<password>>

  $data = array(array(
          "id"                => "9999999",
          "status"            => 1,
          <<rest of the formated data>>
        ));

  $requestData = array(
          'data'     => $data,
          'hash'     => $hash
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
       // $result = json_decode($result, true);

        curl_close($ch);

        die('done :'.$result);
    ?>
```

And here the C# implementation:

```
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.api_url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";          
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    httpWebRequest.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(userName + ":" + password));
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
    }
    tring requestResult = null;
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
    requestResult= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: My best guess is that's it's something with the formatting of the body (for example, the triple-layered array or URL-encoding not being there). However, you only included an example of what works, not what doesn't work. Without any idea of what the code that doesn't work looks like, it's impossible to know for sure *why* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting JSON data, you should set the content type to `application/json`.